# Incrementally Updated Image File Backup Multiple Locations

Tags: oracle, backup, oracle-11g-r2

With an Incrementally Updated Image File Backup the same script handles both the initial image backups, and the incremental backups that can be applied to the images to bring them up to date.  Is there a way to change a parameter or modify this script so that the image files get created in one location and the incrementals get created in another?

A partial solution is to do the inital image file backups, move them to the alternate location and then re-catalog them there.  The next run will then create the incremental backup in the original location, but update the image files in the new location.  The problem comes when a new datafile is created.  The backup will recognize that it doesn't have an image for it and create one, but in the same location as the incrementals.  Aside from repeating the move and re-catalog is there a way to have things happen as desired from the start?

If you're wondering why this would be useful, consider that the image backup volume could be snapped and cloned to a new volume on another server for fast refreshes of lower environments.  Having the incrementals and images in separate locations reduces the space requirements for the snap/clone.

Backup Command:

```
BACKUP INCREMENTAL LEVEL 1 FOR RECOVER OF COPY WITH TAG 'MyImageBackup' DATABASE;
```

Comment: Yes. Just run this command before your backup and point the level 0 backups to one directory and the level 1 backups to a different directory. "configure channel device type disk format '<backup_dir_path>/%d_%Y_%M_%D_%t_%s_%c_%p"

Comment: @Gandolf989 I'm unclear how changing the configuration like this would cause one backup command to behave differently for level 0 than for level 1 backups.  Remember that an incremental level 1 with no level 0 does an implicit level 0, so there is only one backup command that is doing both level 1 and level 0 backups.

Comment: I answered this question. "Is there a way to change a parameter or modify this script so that the image files get created in one location and the incrementals get created in another?" If you do a level 1, point it to one directory, otherwise point to a different directory. Your premise is false though. You can send all backups to the same directory, then the "backup volume could be snapped and cloned to a new volume on another server for fast refreshes of lower environments." As long as you have a block change tracking file, the incremental level 1's should be small compared to the level 0.

Comment: @Gandolf989 See the definition of Incrementally Updating Backups - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/backup.112/e10642/rcmbckba.htm#BRADV8186  Level 1's are significantly smaller than the image files themselves, but not insignificant, which is why I want to exclude them from the snap/clone.

Comment: **Doc ID 831223.1** might be useful for you.

Comment: @JSapkota Were you referring to the part that talks about taking a separate level 1 when a new datafile is created.  I.E. don't run the same backup.  This was what Gandolf989 was indirectly saying as well.  Perhaps someone should make this an answer.  Although it wasn't what I was hoping for, it may be the closest thing to what I want.

Comment: @LeighRiffel: Yes, it's the closest method I found as per my understanding of your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible to have this single backup command do the level 0 to a different location than the level 1.  It is possible to change the script to determine which files don't have level zero backups and do a separate backup just for those datafiles before running the existing command to the incremental location.

Comment: Obviously this isn't the desired answer.  Thanks to @Gandolf989 and JSapkota who both essentially said this.

Comment: @JSapkota (to get a ping)